# Removing Element from Array After Comparison of Different Length Arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays :

```
allLabBranches = {0:{labbranchid: "1", labname: "Main Branch"}, 1 :{labbranchid: "2", labname: "Gulberg branch"}, 2: {labbranchid: "3", labname: "Shahdara Branch"}};

admnuserbrnchs = {0: 1, 1: 2};
```

I want to remove those branches whose ids don't match with the elements of `admnuserbrnchs` elements. My current code is as follows:

```
if(allLabBranches.length >= admnuserbrnchs.length ){
    for(var i =0; i < allLabBranches.length; i++){
        for(var j =0; j < admnuserbrnchs.length; j++){
            if(allLabBranches[i].labbranchid != admnuserbrnchs[j]){

                allLabBranches.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, its result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter` and `.includes` to achieve this.

```js
var allLabBranches = {
  0: {
    labbranchid: "1",
    labname: "Main Branch"
  },
  1: {
    labbranchid: "2",
    labname: "Gulberg branch"
  },
  2: {
    labbranchid: "3",
    labname: "Shahdara Branch"
  }
};
var admnuserbrnchs = {
  0: 1,
  1: 2
};

//Convert the objects to arrays
allLabBranches = Object.values(allLabBranches);
admnuserbrnchs = Object.values(admnuserbrnchs);

//Filter array
var newBranches = allLabBranches.filter(function(v, i) {
  return admnuserbrnchs.includes(Number(v.labbranchid)) ? true : false
});

console.log(newBranches);
```